# DB: Matchmaking and Scoring between multiple columns (3D Data Set)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multidimensional-array

One of my acquaintances inquired about a unique SQL task. They are biotech researchers and hence not well versed with SQL. They operate in Excel, which limited their ability to produce analytics and requested me help with it. And I am equally stumped regarding choosing the approach for this solution, that is programmatic approach or a DB query should suffice. If, DB query, then what it should be? Thinking about this in terms of lines of code and CPU cycles / RAM consumption, as this is a small part of a big system.

The problem set is regarding the match making between the various samples. Each sample has PrimaryKey : MemberID. Each MemberID has 6 parameter scores. Each Parameter is unique and hence cross-matching between the parameters is not allowed. If the parameters match with other samples, the score is 1. Max score is 6 and the Min score is 0. Example set is below :

[image: Data Set : Input in the MySQL Table. Result Set : To be used for further analysis]

The original input is the only dataset. I have visualized the result set.

Below are the conditions:

- Particular score can match with only that particular score. (i.e Score1 can match with only other Score1)
- A look up query which shows matches for a particular MemberID which shows the matches (MemberIDs) (6/6, 6/5 and so on)
- A general Query to display the statistics of the tables (Total of 6/6 matches, 6/5 matches and so on)
- A query to display specific matches (6/6,6/5 or 6/4) and so on.

I thought about transposing the data structure to something like :

[image]

And then use the groupby to generate the result set. But this 3D set is fusing my brain. Tech used for this MySQL and PHP. Any help with the result sets specified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each member, you want the number of matching scores to other members.  I would start with:

```
select s.memberid, s2.memberid,
      ( (s1.score1 = s2.score1) + (s1.score2 = s2.score2) + (s1.score3 = s2.score3) +
        (s1.score4 = s2.score4) + (s.score5 = s2.score5) + (s1.score6 = s2.score6)
      ) as scores_in_common
from sample s join
     sample s2
     on s.memberid <> s2.memberid;
```

This may be enough for what you are doing.  The information is in the result set, but in a different format.

For your particular format:

```
select memberid,
       group_concat(case when scores_in_common = 6 then memberid2 end) as in_common_6,
       group_concat(case when scores_in_common = 5 then memberid2 end) as in_common_5,
       group_concat(case when scores_in_common = 4 then memberid2 end) as in_common_4,
       group_concat(case when scores_in_common = 3 then memberid2 end) as in_common_3,
       group_concat(case when scores_in_common = 2 then memberid2 end) as in_common_2,
       group_concat(case when scores_in_common = 1 then memberid2 end) as in_common_1
from (select s.memberid, s2.memberid as memberid2,
             ( (s1.score1 = s2.score1) + (s1.score2 = s2.score2) + (s1.score3 = s2.score3) +
               (s1.score4 = s2.score4) + (s.score5 = s2.score5) + (s1.score6 = s2.score6)
             ) as scores_in_common
      from sample s join
           sample s2
           on s.memberid <> s2.memberid
     ) ss
where scores_in_common >= 1
group by memberid;
```

Comment: I guess the first format and the first query is cheaper on CPU, but a bit harder on the RAM. Maybe I don't know what I am talking about... but the solution is perfect! Thank you!